# Global Variable vs Local Variable

Tags: metabox, variables, globals

```
// MOVE REVISIONS METABOX TO BOTTOM OF EDIT-FORM.PHP
$post_types = get_post_types();
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'batteryboys_reorder_meta_boxes');
function batteryboys_reorder_meta_boxes(){
    remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv', $post_types, 'normal' );
    add_meta_box('revisionsdiv', __('Revisions'), 'post_revisions_meta_box', $post_types, 'normal', 'low');
}
```

This code works fine, however when you move the `$post_types = get_post_types();` inside of the function, it does not work.

Is this because the get_post_types() function has to be global to execute and by containing it inside the function I am restricting it to just inside the function?  In other words, it can't get out to query the database, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Milo pointed out, when you use code in OP `$post_types` is undefined inside the function, so WordPress will act just like it was not there at all.

However, that means you are using an undefined variable, and if [turn `WP_DEBUG` on](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) you'll see a warning, and so you can notice you are doing something wrong.

That's one of the reasons you **always** should develop with debug turned on.

Regarding your problem, sure run a foreach can be a solution, but is not needed in your case, reason is that **[`'do_meta_boxes'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_meta_boxes/) hook pass screen id** (that is post type name) as argument, so you can use it to remove and add your metabox.

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'batteryboys_reorder_meta_boxes', 1);

function batteryboys_reorder_meta_boxes($screen){
    if ($screen === 'dashboard') return;
    remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv', $screen, 'normal' );
    add_meta_box(
      'revisionsdiv', __('Revisions'), 'post_revisions_meta_box', $screen, 'normal', 'low'
    );
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I had originally used the do_meta_boxes hook, however was having a call to undefined meta box display on the dashboard.

1. How did you know to omit the dashboard in the function?

2. When using $screen as a parameter in the function, what is telling the function we are on the dashboard screen?  How does it know what screen we are on?

Comment: 1) I knew that `'do_meta_boxes'` is fired on dashboard because I know that the [Dashboard Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) use it. 2) The `$screen` argument is passed to function using `do_action` you can see it in [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L270).

Comment: The code works great, however I don't understand what is happening.  When I look at the function reference and the hook reference, it says it requires 3 parameters.  You used only 1.  Why does it work?

Answer (score 2):

`$post_types` is undefined inside your function, `add_meta_box` checks if the value is null and defaults to the current post type when the action runs. That's why it *appears* to work when `$post_types = get_post_types();` is outside, when in reality it's doing nothing.

It doesn't work when you add `$post_types = get_post_types();` inside the function, because that function returns an array and that argument for `add_meta_box` must be a string. It's no longer null, but it's invalid, so it fails.

To make it work you need to loop over the array of post types and call `add_meta_box` for each:

```
function batteryboys_reorder_meta_boxes(){
    $post_types = get_post_types();
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ){
        remove_meta_box( 'revisionsdiv', $post_type, 'normal' );
        add_meta_box('revisionsdiv', __('Revisions'), 'post_revisions_meta_box', $post_type, 'normal', 'low');
    }
}
```